# How to build Telegraher 9.66

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.6.2.300'
    }
}
repositories {
    google()
}
```

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
- https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.2.1/gradle-8.2.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

https://github.com/nikitasius/Telegraher/tree/graher_9.66

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZqdm.png).